# Solr помогите рассчитать потребление ресурсов?

Tags: php, solr

Нужно подобрать сервер для СОЛР, сколько надо памяти и на сколько должен быть мощный сервер. На нем будет крутиться база, в сжатом виде zip она 1гб, в распакованном она где-то ~15гб, в csv формате, это >6 млн строк записей (документов).

Самое важное это нужно ежемесячно ее переиндексировать, делаю это на php через расширение. и по моим расчетам это занимает около 60 часов. Т.к. 1000 документов я загружаю туда за 35сек.  (тест делал на виртуалке, убунту 14х64)